# Execute javascript through 'onCellChange'

Tags: javascript

For an educational pentesting project, I've found a small leak in a guestbook.
The guestbook is filtering all javascript events but it seems like the 'onCellChange' event isn't blocked.

Should I be able to execute Javascript with this tag?

I've tried the folowing wiithout succes :

```
<ELEMENT onCellChange=alert(1)>
```

Comment: Try `onCellChange="javascript:alert(1)"`

Comment: im not sure if helping people that claim to be doing pentesting on real environment, sitll not being able to write a simple js call is ethical...

Comment: I'm a student... The purpose of this is learning to do it.. Thx for your input, but u could simply show me the answer if it's that easy... onCellChange="javascript:alert(1)" doesn't work as well...

Answer (score 0):

The main question is what the intention is and where is that `alert(1)` coming from. If that script is coming from the developer team with the intention of displaying 1 on cell change, then it is a good thing to have and there is no problem. If a Javascript is coming from a user input, then it is an attempt of [XSS injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) which should be prevented from executing.

All in all, the answer to your question largely depends on the context.

Comment: The goal is to perform an XSS injection. The question is... Is my syntax correct. Cuz even local this doesn't executes.